# Searching for a solution for more memory friendly way while adding elements to a list of class in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to produce a runtime table. Below class and codes are simplified version of my final purpose.

```
class AppModel {
  int appID;
  String appName;
  AppModel({this.appID, this.appName});
}
```

I'm calculating, fetching some another data and trying to fill the following object like this:

```
// _newApps value is between 1-30 mostly but not limited

List<AppModel> theList = [];

for (int i = 0; i < _newApps; i++) {
  AppModel _newRecord = AppModel();
  _newRecord.appID = _getNewAppID();
  _newRecord.appName = _getNewAppName();
  theList.add(_newRecord);
}
```

So the question is the code creates a new AppModel instance for only adding the element to the list for every iteration inside the for loop. According to my program logic, this event can be repeated 100-150 times sometimes.

Is it normal or is there any more memory efficient way to do so?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to point out (a better approach) that instead of for Loop you could have used the map method on the Apps List you have. And instead of creating a object every time in the Loop create a constructor for returning the object instance using the required details.

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. Apperantly this is the best way to do so.